# Typescript useState<string> ReferenceError: string is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

```js
import React, {
  FunctionComponent,
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react'

const SearchBar: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState < string > ('')
  const [isSuggestionOpen, setIsSuggestionOpen] = useState < boolean > (false)

  async function showSuggestedWords(event) {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value)

    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://www.someurl.com/q=${searchValue}`)
      const suggestedWordsArray = await res.json()
      // setSuggestedWords(suggestedWordsArray[1].slice(0, 10))
      setIsSuggestionOpen(true)
      return
    } catch {
      console.log('error fetching suggested results')
      setIsSuggestionOpen(false)
    }
  }


  return ( <
    div >
    <
    form action = "/Controller"
    method = "get" >
    <
    input name = "q"
    type = "text"
    value = {
      searchValue
    }
    onChange = {
      showSuggestedWords
    }
    autoComplete = "off"
    autoCapitalize = "off"
    autoCorrect = "off"
    spellCheck = "false"
    placeholder = "Search here" /
    >
    <
    button type = "submit" >
    Submit <
    /button> <
    /form> <
    /div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render( <
  div > < h1 > Hello, world! < /h1> <SearchBar / > < /div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/4.0.3/typescript.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I'm new to typescript so it might be a obvious solution.

I have a project made with React, Nextjs and Typescript.

I use typescript to define my state type like so:
`const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('')`

And I get an error at runtime:
`ReferenceError: string is not defined`.

I can't figured out what's wrong. Everywhere i check they suggest to define state type like i did above.

Here are my typescript config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I don't have webpack config because they are shipped with Nextjs (which is already configured to work with typescript.)

I do have `@types/react @types/react-dom @types/node` installed.

Any hint?

Comment: What does the compiled code where the error occurs looks like? The `<string>` shouldn't have been emitted - and even if it was, that'd throw a SyntaxError

Comment: good point! That's what can i found in the compiled code `var _ref = _react.useState < string > '',`

Comment: The function call parentheses get lost? Sounds like something's really broken. Are you in a `ts` or `tsx` file, or in a `js` file?

Comment: You called setSearchValue not with a string... Do you have reproducible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @CertainPerformance i use `tsx`. The bunlde is made by Nextjs and splitted so I'm not 100% sure the code i wrote is the actual compiled code we are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out it was some mismatching configuration in my `babel.config.json`

I removed everything and kept just those lines:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"]
    }
  }
}
```

In this way I still can run my Jest tests.

Hopefully it can be helpful for someone else in this situation :)